# Navigate to previous page from grails controller?

Tags: grails, controller

Is there a way to navigate previous page from grails Controller and pass model to be rendered, for example I'm having page and want to navigate user/register and to revert to the previous url if there are errors in form?

currently I'm having

```
def register = {
 ...
    return [user : user]
}
```

Thanks,
Mika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're writing a [webflow](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#webflow)[image]

Webflows are really the only game in town if you need to manage non-persistent state across multiple pages. Fortunately, webflow provides built-in support for your requirement - going back to the form page if validation fails.

Comment: they can be a bit tricky to get right, but if you want to manage state over multiple pages, it's the only way to do it properly

Comment: Thank you Don, that response made me LOL for real. Looks like it's time for IDE clippy integration!

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions killer idea, if you're looking for a partner in this venture, I'm in!